# Angular SCSS variables whilst using `innerHTML`

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, css-variables

I have the following in my component where the HTML is a string pulled from a database.

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHTML | safeHtml"></div>
```

The HTML generated has a class called 'mainColour' on one of the elements. However, when changing a colour in my application, the variable is updated, but the element isn't.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', primary);
```

If the HTML is inserted directly into the component, instead of using `innerHTML`, it works fine.

Is there way to ensure css variables work with elements that are produced as a part of `innerHTML`?

Comment: Did you try using `safeStyle` piped after `safeHtml`?

Comment: Is there a `safeStyle` pipe?

Comment: you can copy it from [here](https://gist.github.com/Walgermo/ba3b58ade49eed1372e082d58ff750d7)

Comment: ah thanks! - Get an error with `Error: Required a safe HTML, got a Style`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the `.scss` file, you need to add the following before your class names.

```
:host ::ng-deep
```

For example:

```
$primary: var(--primary-color);
$secondary: var(--secondary-color);


:host ::ng-deep.primary-background {
  background-color: $primary;
}

:host ::ng-deep.secondary-background {
  background-color: $secondary;
}
```